# passing parameter to Dataenvironment visual basic

Tags: vb6

HI,

I am working on Visual Basic DataEnvironment I have written SQL command but i need to pass some parameter from one of my form object.
I have tried this

```
SELECT * from user WHERE userid= form1.textbox1.text
```

but it doesn't seems to be work. Any Idea how to pass parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest performing a filter on the recordset inside your DataEnviroment instead placing the WHERE clause where your SQL statement is defined.

```
With DataEnvironment1.rsDataTable
  .Filter = "UserID = " & textbox1.text
End With
```

Please check out the following links.  I hope this helps.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231245(v=vs.60).aspx
http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~saul/vb_examples/tutorial4/index.html

Also, if possible I would recommend using ADO instead of the DataEnvironment.